# My laptop's keyboard stops working; zc,xv/.M?

Tags: keyboard

I don't know what that means.  Does anyone know what zc,xv/.M is for?

Answer (score 0):

I can only refer to this: http://discussions.virtualdr.com/showthread.php?t=169193